# Smooth gradient overlay on image in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app, gradient, overlay

I'm working on a music app in Sketch where the top part of the screen is a full-bleed album art that fades into a dark background. There will be some content on top of the album art, so I've applied a gradient overlay to the bottom of the image. The problem I'm having is that there seems to be a strong line where the background and image meet (where the gradient starts). I've tried manually adding extra stops to the gradient, but can't seem to get it right. Has anyone had success with this before? I've added an example of my setup...

[image: gradient overlay]

Comment: I think before you try anything exotic I'd try intentionally ***not*** aligning the image edge with the edge of your transparency mask - I'd have the image *bleed* by 5+ pixels below the edge of the 100% opaque part of the transparency mask... see if that licks your issue in the simplest, Occam's Razor approved manner!

Comment: @GerardFalla, I'm not sure this would work since the image/overlay are on top of the dark background, so if the image were to bleed below the edge, it would be visible on top of the background, right?

Comment: Gotcha. I'd say you want a dark background for the image to float in front of, and that then you want a layer *above* the image, which contains your gradient transparency mask and a dark fore-background as well, which obscures your image's bleed area. All other elements float above this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the linearity of the gradient — going from one color to another, with no stops in between.

What you'll want is a gradient that follows more of a natural curve, as you'd see in a natural environment with soft lighting.

[image: Visual difference between a linear gradient and one that has easing]

Luckily, there's a Sketch plugin that helps make it way easier 
https://larsenwork.com/easing-gradients/

I use this plugin everyday, and couldn't imagine living without it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much...and having a plugin is amazing!